# Как в woocommerce перевести billing поля на разные языки?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины, polylang

Есть магазин на `woocommerce` с установленным плагином мультиязычности [polylang](https://polylang.pro).

Мне нужно перевести лейблы *billing полей* на разные языки.

Простые словесные конструкции на страницах я перевожу с помощью комбинации:
в **functions.php** прописываю фразу

```
pll_register_string( 'themename', 'CHOSE DATES' );
```

Перевожу ее на странице плагина и затем вывожу на любой странице с помощью

```
pll_e( 'CHOSE DATES' );
```

Но, для лейблов такой подход не прокатывает, т.к. вызов их идет через фильтр *woocommerce_checkout_fields* и выводит на месте лейбла пустоту, а в произвольном месте на странице перевод..

**functions.php**

```
pll_register_string( 'themename', 'CHOSE DATES' );
// Hook in
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
     $fields['billing']['billing_first_name']['label']  = pll_e( 'CHOSE DATES' );
     return $fields;
}
```

Как решить эту задачку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `pll_e()` транслирует и **выводит** строку. Вам нужно заменить её на `pll__()`, которая возвращает транслированную строку.

```
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing']['billing_first_name']['label'] = pll__( 'CHOSE DATES' );

    return $fields;
}
```